# Tesseract-OCR cannot read traineddata

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I'm using Tess4J for java and it works when I use the default tessdata however when I train a new set (with a new font) using https://github.com/livezingy/tesstrainsh-win I get the error:

```
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:470)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:404)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.getOCRText(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
```

but I can properly test the newly trained `eng.traineddata` using `eval.sh` & `lstmeval`

When I open both files they are vastly different, the original trainneddata has a readable format and the new one doesn't initially I thought it was corrupted somehow but being able to use `eval.sh` makes me thing otherwise.

This is both traineddata on the editor, the left one is the newly trained one and the right one is the original one that came with tess4j
[image: Difference between both train]

This is what my code looks like:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        File imageFile = new File("assets/screenshot_22.png");
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
            System.out.println("result: " + result);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

I've seen some posts of people saying you need to set do `instance.setDataPath("abs-path-to-tessdata")` but that is not the issue, I've tried that already and is the same result with the different `tessdata`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You may need to call `setOcrEngineMode​`.

Comment: @nguyenq same errors, regardless one the moded (0~3)